# Is there a more specific name for this type of arithmetic puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, puzzle-identification

There are arithmetic puzzles with some numbers (typically four) and rules for combining them (perhaps just the four basic arithmetic operators or including things like combining digits 2 and 3 to make numbers like 23).

[Write twenty-four from four numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/623/write-twenty-four) is an example which was recently posed on this site.

What is the general name of this type of puzzle, or is it just an "arithmetic puzzle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not heard any special name for them before.

But [here](https://erich-friedman.github.io/puzzle/form/), such puzzles are called "Number Formation Puzzles," and if you google, you can find "About 26,300 results", so it is more or less a common name.

Meanwhile, if you google arithmetic puzzles you can find many different types of such a puzzles:

- [Verbal arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_arithmetic)
- [Mental Arithmetic](http://www.thepuzzleclub.com/mental-arithmetic.php)
- [Math puzzles](http://www.riddleriders.com/math-puzzles/arithmetic-puzzles)
- and others, practically any imaginary puzzle, which involves arithmetic is called with such a name by somebody.