# Think not in integers?

Tags: mathematics

Easier again:

Make 24 using only the digits 1, 4, 5 and 6, with the following conditions:

- They should not be clubbed /joined (to form such as 64 or 51 etc.)
- Only the basic arithmetic operations (+, -, * and /) are allowed to be performed. (Means - No use of powers / roots / factorials etc.)
- All the given digits should be used and
- All the given digits should be used only once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write twenty-four from four numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/623/write-twenty-four-from-four-numbers)

Comment: @bleh No, $\{1,3,4,6\}\neq\{1,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: Yea, but it's the same concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is easy as I think it is

> $6/(5/4-1)$

Which simplifies to

> $6*4$

Which is 24

Or you can do it the other way...

> $4/(1-5/6)$

Which simplifies to

> $4*6$

Comment: Well, good work @bleh (fast enough), though there is another way to achieve the same (can be considered as a bonus !)

Comment: Yes, @bleh, you got the other one also correct !

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is very similar to the answer here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1641/10399

$\dfrac{6}{\frac{5}{4} - 1}$.

This simplifies to $\frac{6}{1/4}$, which becomes $6 \cdot 4$, which becomes $24$.

Comment: Well, good work @Ian MacDonald, though there is another way to achieve the same (can be considered as a bonus !)

Comment: You should probably checkmark @bleh's answer. I literally just copy-pasted mine and changed the first formula a bit to match your inputs.